JSF 3.0 on Tomcat 10.x throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
I created a new Maven project and would like to use Tomcat 10.1.20 and JDK 21
my application doesn't start and gives the error: :
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [Faces Servlet] in web application [/MyProject_maven] threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:491)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:473)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:865)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:805)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4631)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4924)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:635)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:484)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1703)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1477)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:971)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:334)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:41002)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

this is my maven pom.xml :
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProject_maven</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>MyProject_maven</name>
    
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jakarta.faces.version>3.0.0</jakarta.faces.version>
    <weld.version>5.1.0.Final</weld.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    <jakartaee>10.0.0</jakartaee>
  </properties>
    
  <dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.security.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.security.enterprise-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    

   
    
  </dependencies>
  
   
    
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>21</source>
          <target>21</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

I've done a lot of testing by changing the maven configuration above, but I can't launch the application!
I followed this answer, but without success:
How to properly configure Jakarta EE libraries in Maven pom.xml for Tomcat?

thank you very much BalusC !!..
just a little opinion from you.. what do you think about the future of JSF? Is it a technology in decline?

Nope. It's still going on and actively maintained. There's even a recent increase. People are starting to get fed up with verboseness of overhyped frameworks.

ok thanks!
do you know Apache Shiro? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78449680/apache-shiro-integration-in-jsf-3-0

Yes but since JEE8 there's built-in Security API: https://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-8-security. No need for 3rd party libraries/dependencies anymore.
