Apache Shiro integration in JSF 3.0+
I created a new Maven project that run with Tomcat 10.1.20 and JDK 21.
Now I want to integrate Apache Shiro, but my application doesn't start and gives the error:
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener]
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:491)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:473)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.ForwardingInstanceManager.newInstance(ForwardingInstanceManager.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.WeldForwardingInstanceManager.newInstance(WeldForwardingInstanceManager.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4890)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:635)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:484)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1703)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1477)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:971)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:334)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:41002)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

this is my pom.xml file
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.afterbit.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>my app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>myapp</name>
    
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
    
  <dependencies>
    
    
 
    <!-- For Tomcat 10.1.x, which is based on Servlet 6.0, JSP 3.1, EL 5.0, WS 2.1 and JASIC 3.0, you should use jakarta.* imports and the entire <dependencies> section should minimally look like: -->
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.security.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.security.enterprise-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- JSTL on Tomcat 10.1.x -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Mojarra 3.0 or 4.0 on Tomcat 10 or newer -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- CDI implementation / Weld -->   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

        
    <!-- END For Tomcat 10.1.x, which is based on Servlet 6.0, JSP 3.1, EL 5.0, WS 2.1 and JASIC 3.0, you should use jakarta.* imports and the entire <dependencies> section should minimally look like: -->

    <!-- OmniFaces 4.x requires Java 11, Faces 3.0, EL 4.0, Servlet 5.0, CDI 3.0, WS 2.0 -->    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.32</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <!--log4j2 dependencies -->
    <!-- This is the needed core component. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- This is the needed API component. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
 
        
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <!--disruptor for log4j2 async logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
      <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--END log4j2 dependencies -->
    
    
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
      <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
      <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    


    <!-- Apache Commons -->
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-exec -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <!-- END Apache Commons -->
        
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>   
    
    <!-- microsoft jdbc driver -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>12.6.1.jre11</version>
    </dependency> 
    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/c3p0/c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- EclipseLink -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END EclipseLink -->
    
    
    
    <!-- JAXB -->
   
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.5</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- END JAXB -->
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity-engine-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
      <artifactId>velocity-engine-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jodd/jodd-mail -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
      <artifactId>jodd-mail</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
  </dependencies>
  
   
    
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>21</source>
          <target>21</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

a the web.xml file :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
         version="6.0">
   
  
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
  
  
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    <!-- Disables URL-based sessions (no more 'jsessionid' in the URL using Tomcat) -->
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>
  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

I tried to change different versions of Apache Shiro without success. I also followed this article:
https://shiro.apache.org/jakarta-ee.html
but the error remains!..

as in the article above:
look at "How to use Jakarta 9+.." and add also "Shiro BOM.." and it works!

You need to use 2.x+ of Shiro if you are using the Jakarta packages.
Here is a (non-JSF) example:
https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/main/samples/web-jakarta/pom.xml
